# Override default-lazy-init=true for Spring bean definitions

Tags: java, spring

I am maintaining a large Java EE system. Most of the business logic is converted from EJB:s into POJO:s configured in several spring context configuration files. EJB:s are mostly used as Facades, that looks up the business logic spring beans from a context composed of all spring context configuration files mentioned earlier. For this we use the AbstractStatelessSessionBean provided with the spring framework.

All these configuration files have the default-lazy-init=true directive, which means that the business logic beans are not created until they are actually used by the system. This is preferable most of the time since republishing in developer mode becomes faster.

But when large merges are made, we are having problems finding all the configuration errors, such as missing dependencies.

My idea is to write some form of integration test, with the purpose of finding those errors. This means, i think, that I need to find a way to override all default-lazy-init=true declarations when creating the application context.

Is there any way of doing this programmatically, or perhaps with some test-only context file that includes all the actual context files?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that EJB3 beans are just as much POJOs as are `POJO:s configured in several spring context configuration files`.

Comment: Ok, we are stuck with EJB 2.x for the moment. We will probably move to EJB 3 in the future though.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. EJB 2 is a device invented to torture developers :( Hope you'll be able to move to EJB 3 soon (it's from 2006 btw so it's really not that new)

Answer (score 15):

Let's say currently you have a single `applicationContext.xml` file containing all bean definitions:

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">

    <!-- all your beans -->

</beans>
```

Rename it to `applicationContext-main.xml` or something and remove `default-lazy-init="true"` attribute. Now create two `applicationContext.xml` files:

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">

    <import resource="applicationContext-core.xml"/>

</beans>
```

and:

```
<beans default-lazy-init="false">

    <import resource="applicationContext-core.xml"/>

</beans>
```

As you can see the only difference is the value of `default-lazy-init`. During development your team can use the former version of `applicationContext.xml` that includes all the beans with `lazy-init`. On staging and testing environments switch it to the latter so that all beans included in `applicationContext-core.xml` are created eagerly.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. Our configuration files have a rather complex structure of includes, I will see what I can make of this.

Comment: Have you ever test this? `<beans default-lazy-init="false">

    <import resource="applicationContext-core.xml"/>

</beans>` can not make beans eagerly init.

Comment: For my version of Spring, 3.1.2, setting default-lazy-init on the top level beans element does not apply to beans inside an imported resource. In this, I agree with pootow. Who knows whether it works under a different version of spring; it'd be lovely to. What I had to do was as Jon said.

Comment: It works under Spring 3.2.3 (not checked for lesser version). However you must remove default-lazy-init/lazy-init attributes or set them to "default" to use "inheritance" (parent defaults).

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the best way is to control lazy init of beans is to leave the default-lazy-init out of all config files except the topmost as Tomasz Nurkiewicz suggests. I did however in this case need a quick and dirty fix to verify all bean definitions. (It is a bit of a process to change the lazy init policy.)

I came up with a simple BeanFactoryPostProcessor which seems to do the job:

```
public class NonLazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setLazyInit(false);
        }
    }
}
```

If included in a context file, it will override the lazy init flag set by any included context files.

```
<beans default-lazy-init="false">
    <bean class="example.NonLazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-core.xml"/>
</beans>
```

If I try to create a context from the above xml, configuration errors previously hidden by lazy initialization will show up immediately as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is one 'but' in this PostProcessor

```
for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setLazyInit(false);
    }
```

This for loop will iterate only over top most beans not including e.g internal(local) bean defintions ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the scanner from the context - it's completely private, but since you can step into the source code, you can see what's required to set up your own. I used Spring's own ReflectionTestUtils to set my own configured scanner in the context:

```
    ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(context);
    BeanDefinitionDefaults defaults = new BeanDefinitionDefaults();
    defaults.setLazyInit(true);
    scanner.setBeanDefinitionDefaults(defaults);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(context, "scanner", scanner);
    context.scan("com.some.path");
```

You can do this anywhere you have access to the Application Context before the component scan takes place.